# Cannot load local file into PySpark Dataframe

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, local-files

I am a MacOS user and I just downloaded Apache Spark. I then put it in `/usr/local/spark`.
Here is what inside my `.bash_profile`:

```
export SPARK_HOME="/usr/local/spark"
export PYSPARK_PYTHON=python3
export PATH=$PATH:$SPARK_HOME/bin
#export PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON="jupyter"
#export PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON_OPTS="notebook"
```

The problem is, when type pyspark to enter the pyspark shell, then type these two lines:

```
spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("preprocessing").config("spark-master", "local").getOrCreate()
df = spark.read.format("csv").option("header","true").option("inferSchema", "true").option("delimiter",",").load("src/census-income.data")
```

An error occurs:

```
2018-10-02 19:55:24 ERROR PoolWatchThread:118 - Error in trying to obtain a connection. Retrying in 7000ms
java.sql.SQLException: A read-only user or a user in a read-only database is not permitted to disable read-only mode on a connection.
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.SQLExceptionFactory.getSQLException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.Util.generateCsSQLException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.TransactionResourceImpl.wrapInSQLException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.TransactionResourceImpl.handleException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedConnection.handleException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedConnection.setReadOnly(Unknown Source)
    at com.jolbox.bonecp.ConnectionHandle.setReadOnly(ConnectionHandle.java:1324)
    at com.jolbox.bonecp.ConnectionHandle.<init>(ConnectionHandle.java:262)
    at com.jolbox.bonecp.PoolWatchThread.fillConnections(PoolWatchThread.java:115)
    at com.jolbox.bonecp.PoolWatchThread.run(PoolWatchThread.java:82)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: ERROR 25505: A read-only user or a user in a read-only database is not permitted to disable read-only mode on a connection.
    at org.apache.derby.iapi.error.StandardException.newException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.iapi.error.StandardException.newException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.conn.GenericAuthorizer.setReadOnlyConnection(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.conn.GenericLanguageConnectionContext.setReadOnly(Unknown Source)
    ... 8 more
```

- Spark version: 2.3.2
- Python version: 3.7.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try deleting the file **metastore_db/dbex.lck** from the current directory (SPARK_HOME)?

Source: https://github.com/bpn1/ingestion/wiki/Troubleshooting

Answer (score 0):

Spark is trying to load from HDFS. Apparently you don't have hadoop installed and spark is failing to connect to HDFS.
If you want to load from load you have to specify this explicitly:

`file:///src/census-income.data`